# 2 функции int main()

Tags: c++, cmake, link, компоновщик, линковка

У меня есть файл `foo.cpp`, который содержит определения некоторых функций и функцию `int main()`. Этот файл является отдельным таргетом и может быть запущен (`add_executable(foo foo.cpp)`).

Ещё у меня есть файл `bar.cpp`, который включает в себя файл `foo.hpp` (содержащий объявления некоторых функций из `foo.cpp`), но также содержит другой `int main()`.

Задача состоит в том, чтобы иметь возможность сделать таргет для `bar.cpp`, но для этого к объявлениям из `foo.hpp` надо прилинковать определения из файла `foo.cpp`. Однако при линковке возникает ошибка из-за двух функций `int main()`. То же самое, если сделать из `foo.cpp` библиотеку и прилинковать к таргету `bar`.

Как можно решить эту проблему? Можно ли как-то прилинковать `foo` к `bar` без функции `int main()` из `foo.cpp`? Или выбрать из двух функций единственную, чтобы не было ошибки?

Файлы:

> foo.cpp
>
> foo.hpp
>
> bar.cpp

CMake:

```
add_executable(foo foo.cpp)

add_executable(bar bar.cpp)
add_library(foo_lib foo.cpp foo.hpp)
target_link_libraries(bar foo_lib) # Ошибка линковки: 2 функции int main()
```

Важно: файл `foo.cpp` менять нельзя, всё остальное можно.

Comment: Очень странно что библиотека `foo` содержит `main` функцию. С/C++ библиотеки по своему определению не должны содержать входную точку, так как это всего лишь набор функций (или классов) вызываемые из основного бинарника, которая должна содержать единственную функцию `main` - ваш дизайн заставляет вас строить костыли чтобы избежать ошибки двойного определения, это плохая практика.

Comment: @ampawd я знаю, что в `foo.cpp` не должно быть мэйна, но он там есть и править его не могу, поэтому указал это в вопросе

Comment: почему? она написана не вами ? если так то стоит уточнить у автора для каких целей в ней существует фукнция `main`

Comment: Это тоже проблема XY. Отчего вдруг foo.cpp нельзя править, но при этом пытаетесь линковать к другой единице трансляции? Приводите исходную задачу.

Comment: Это внешний файл, я не могу его менять. Почему я не могу этого делать не относится к теме вопроса

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну сделать, например, файл foo_wrapper.cpp:

```cpp
#include <foo.hpp>

#define main this_is_not_main
#include "foo.cpp"
```

Comment: Нет, вряд ли. Что за ошибки конкретно?

Answer (score -1):

Каждую из функций main обернуть в `#if`, например:

```
#if FOO_IS_MAIN
  int main()
  {
    ...
  }
#endif
```

А при компиляции указывать соответствующую константу.

Comment: foo.cpp нельзя править.

Comment: @bipll 1. Почему? 2. Тогда соседний ответ.

Comment: Потому что см. последнюю строку вопроса.