# Объявление и определение шаблонного класса в cpp файле

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, link, компоновщик, линковка

Можно ли объявить и определить шаблонный класс в `.cpp` файле, а потом использовать некоторые его инстанциации (заранее известные) в другом `.cpp` файле, который линкуется с первым?

Если я объявляю и определяю шаблонный класс `A` в первом файле `foo.cpp`, то, включая такое же объявление этого класса из `foo.hpp` (`foo.hpp` не включается в `foo.cpp`) в `bar.cpp`, происходят ошибки линковки. Если в `foo.cpp` заранее явно инстанцировать нужные классы, то ошибок на этапе сборки нет, но при первом использовании метода класса вываливается `SIGSEGV`.

Файлы из этого вопроса [2 функции int main()](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1036574/355753).

Comment: Если объявить в заголовочном файле - то да, можно.

Comment: @VTT объявить в .cpp файле

Comment: @VTT то есть компилируемом

Comment: Ну тогда нет...

Comment: @VTT наверное, не так вас понял. Если я объявил и определил шаблонный класс в .cpp файле, то 1) я могу использовать любые инстанции этого класса в том же .cpp файле? 2) я могу заранее скомпилировать некоторые инстанции этого класса в этом файле, а потом прилинковать этот файл к другому .cpp файлу и там использовать эти определения?

Comment: Во втором cpp файле, нет информации об этом шаблоне. Компилируются два cpp файла раздельно. Значит тип неизвестен.

Comment: 1) да 2) нет, потому что для того, чтобы использовать эти определения, объявления должны быть доступны

Comment: а если добавить объявление в `.hpp` файл и включить этот файл только во второй `.cpp`?

Comment: А зачем его включать только во второй, а не в оба? Это же постоянная бессмысленная борьба с рассинхроном будет.

Comment: @VTT в первый не могу включать по условию, но могу сделать явные инстанциации, например

Comment: По какому еще условию? Это у вас случаем не проблема XY?

Comment: @VTT да, это она. Правильно будет всё в заголовочных файлах определять, но у меня такой набор предусловий, что в первый файл не могу ничего включать/делать макросы и т.д.. Можно сказать, что это файл библиотеки короче, только явные инстанции делать можно

Comment: первый файл это `foo.cpp`, а второй -- `bar.cpp` из этого вопроса https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1036574/355753

Comment: @VTT дополнил вопрос

Comment: @AlexGlebe дополнил вопрос

Comment: Лучше удалите эти вопросы и создайте вопрос с задачей, которая у вас есть на самом деле.

Comment: @VTT это и есть задача. На первый вопрос я получил ответ тем более

Comment: `SIGSEGV` у вас происходит из-за багов в вашем коде и никакого отношения к вопросу не имеет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот как это делается - в файле с реализацией указывается **явное инстанцирование** нужного типа.

Ваше "включение .cpp" в другой файл - это по сути просто дать заголовочному файлу разрешение .cpp - вы его отдельно не компилируете...

**a.h**

```
template<class T>
void foo();

template<class T>
class Hren
{
public:
    void zadolbal();
};
```

**a.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "a.h"

using namespace std;


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    foo<char>();
    foo<int>();

    Hren<char> c;
    Hren<double> d;
    c.zadolbal();
    d.zadolbal();
}
```

**b.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
#include "a.h"

using namespace std;

template<class T>
void foo()
{
    cout << typeid(T).name() << endl;
}

template<class T>
void Hren<T>::zadolbal()
{
    cout << typeid(T).name() << endl;
}

template class Hren<char>;
template class Hren<double>;


template void foo<char>();
template void foo<int>();
```

После этого можно компилировать... Например, в VC++:

```
G:\Tmp\Test>cl /EHsc a.cpp b.cpp
Оптимизирующий компилятор Microsoft (R) C/C++ версии 19.16.27034 для x64
(C) Корпорация Майкрософт (Microsoft Corporation).  Все права защищены.

a.cpp
b.cpp
Создание кода...
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.16.27034.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

/out:a.exe
a.obj
b.obj
```

Заметим - компилируются *оба* .cpp-файла.

Comment: Они может и компилируются, но при использовании выдает ошибку сегментации

Comment: Первый файл не может включать заголовочный файл потому что

Comment: Не морочьте мне голову. [Смотрите, если не верите](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KZNBQnqiFOXefwg9Ix0sCv-b_BMC1rFe/view?usp=sharing). Как вы ухитрились скомпилировать так, чтоб получить ошибку - не знаю, это надо уметь... я так не умею.

Comment: У меня классы, а тут функции

Comment: Это что-то меняет? :) Держите с классами. Или опять сделаете *что-то свое*, а мне будете говорить, что ошибка сегментации? :)

Comment: А вообще - вы правы. Вставляйте-ка лучше один .cpp в другой. Как в том анекдоте - "Знаете что, Иван Иванович, не выпендривайтесь и слушайте свои "Валенки"..."

Comment: В целях оптимизации процесса компиляции можно также добавить в заголовочный файл объявления явных инстанцирований (со словом `extern`). Это опционально, но в С++11 такая возможность была введена именно для этого.

Answer (score -1):

Разобрался. Достаточно просто включить **.cpp** файл `wrapped_foo.cpp` в `bar.cpp`

Comment: Включение файла в другой по сути делает его просто заголовочным файлом... У вас же в условии - "который линкуется с первым"...

Comment: Это не решение, а полное избегание исходного вопроса. Так что никакого "разобрался" тут нет и близко.